# I thought/ didn't think you were/ not coming

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, difference, semantics

We  usually  say :

I  don't  think he will  pass.

Not

I think he  will  not  pass.

I didn't think  he  was  coming.

But  not  I  thought  you were not coming.

I know  that  it  is  called  transferred  negation.

I  found  the  sentence   without  transferred  negation in  Michael  swan' s  practical  English  usage.It  is  said that it  is  used to  Indicate  surprise.But  the  explanation  is  not  clear.

What  is  the  difference  between  thse  two  sentences.?

> **I  didn't think  you  were  coming**
>
> **I thought  you  were not  coming?**

**This  is  not  a  duplicate  of  the  previous  post  transferred  negation**

Comment: ***Why*** do you say this isn't a duplicate of [transferred negation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29668/transferred-negation)? Your example is no different to those of the earlier question - and as most of the answers there make clear, in practice ***it makes no difference*** to the meaning whether you negate the "mental process verb" *(think, suppose, believe, etc.)* or the "thing [not] thought".

Comment: @ FumbleFingers.The  OP  asked  which  verbs  allow  the  transferred  negation  which  others   do  not.After  posting  I  saw  the  post  found  it  different.If  you think  it is  almost  the  same, you  may bring  it out  as  a duplicateb

Comment: It's not easy to come up with contexts where there's a clear distinction between the two phrasings.But [this one from a comment to a related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177675/is-there-a-functional-difference-between-not-believing-and-believing-not) isn't bad - contrasting *I don't believe cold showers are good for you* (usually, *they're **of no benefit***, contrary to what some people might claim) and *I believe cold showers are not good for you* (they're ***actually harmful***).

Answer (score 0):

If we boil it down to a very literal sense we can see how it indicates surprise.

> I didn't think you were coming.

Essentially, I "didn't think" of you - this can sound more distant/indifferent than:

> I thought you weren't coming.

In this expression, I **did** think of you ("I thought") - the fact that you had been thinking about this could imply emotion either way, perhaps you are happy that they came, or perhaps you are angry or upset (this would be conveyed by your tone) - either way, you thought about it, and care about it. Perhaps we could argue that it implies, not so much surprise, but a degree of personal/emotional involvement/investment.